# How can I run cronjobs in kubernetes PHP pods?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, centos7, google-kubernetes-engine

I have Kubernetes replication controller which is running 2 pods of PHP applicaton. Now, I need to schedule 3 cronjobs which run some PHP scripts in those pods. How can I achieve it? (The base image for the container is centos:7).

Comment: Did you check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/ ?

Comment: But, What I understood there is, it will create the seperate pod for running scheduled jobs. But, how can I link the cronjob to my application-pod so it can run the scripts of my applicaton-pod?

Comment: Your corn jobs can call the http://myapp.default/myscript.php (exposed by a service) inside the cluster. There are other ways as well - but I guess this is the simplest one

Comment: myapp.default is podname.namespace?

Comment: yes - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns

Comment: Actually name.namespace is for services. To connect to a pod, it is podname.namespace.pod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments your best option is create [Kubernetes CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).

If you don't want to expose you PHP functions, you can always use a container that execute commands in your PHP pods.

Here is an example that create a cronjob. This cronjob runs kubectl exec for every pod with label app=my-php, calling ls in each pod.

```
  apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
  kind: CronJob
  metadata:
    name: hello-cron
  spec:
    schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
    jobTemplate:
      spec:
        template:
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: kubectl
              image: lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
              args: 
                - kubectl get pod -l app=my-php -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -i kubectl exec {} ls
            restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your answer. The above script is working for os provided commands. But, when I try to execute my script, I am getting         "rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused :exec format error ". But., I am able to execute script when I go inside the container.